# How to select rows with matching rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
First tabel called:(data):
---------------------------------------- 
id    link    number    isik    status
---------------------------------------- 
1    /link    78788     56677     55

Second table called:(test)
----------------------------------------
id     kood     status
----------------------------------------
1      56677     111
```

The only similar thing in two tables are the isik and kood

How can I get all the rows from the **First table** where `isik(First table) = kood(Second table)`?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT data * FROM data INNER JOIN test ON data.isik = test.kood";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Numb: " . $row["number"]. " - Name: " . $row["isik"]. " " . $row["link"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

But im getting 0 results

Comment: i have tried INNER JOINT and double query

Comment: It should be `SELECT data.*`, not `SELECT data *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables together using an inner join and select only rows from the first table. This will select only rows where the second table has a matching value for `isik`.

```
SELECT `data`.* FROM `data` INNER JOIN `test` ON `data`.`isik` = `test`.`kood`
```

Comment: This will give 0 results.

Comment: @Gunarves I noticed you accepted the answer. Did changing it to `data.*` solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM First a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM Second b
          WHERE a.isik = b.isik);
```